# Sql Query Select One Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This [screenshot](http://i.hizliresim.com/Kgb6lL.jpg) is my result.

How can I take top record in  Same ID ? (query result have 3 record but i want to take top record)

Thank You 
My Code İs  but i have error (The column 'ID' was specified multiple times for 'CTE'.)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.Product.ID ORDER BY dbo.Picture.UpdatedDate ASC), *
   FROM Dbo.Product
   inner JOIN dbo.Product_Picture_Mapping on dbo.Product_Picture_Mapping.ProductID = dbo.Product.ID
   inner join dbo.Picture on dbo.Picture.ID = dbo.Product_Picture_Mapping.PictureID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY dbo.Picture.UpdatedDate DESC
```

Comment: Use `select top 1 *` instead of `select *`.

Comment: Append 'limit 1' to the same query

Comment: @Madhu: OP is using sql-server.

Comment: Please post your sample data and query here instead of as image. Links will die.

Comment: OK. how about rownum <= 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inherent "top" or "bottom" so you need to specify the column(s) you want to order by.  However, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to get one record per ID.

For example(assuming `UPDATEDDATE` as order-column):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY UPDATEDDATE ASC), *
   FROM rbo.Product INNER JOIN ....
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY UPDATEDDATE DESC
```

(replace `....` with the joins, i didn't want to type them from your image)

Comment: 'code' WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.Product.ID ORDER BY dbo.Picture.UpdatedDate ASC), *
   FROM Dbo.Product
   inner JOIN dbo.Product_Picture_Mapping on dbo.Product_Picture_Mapping.ProductID = dbo.Product.ID
   inner join dbo.Picture on dbo.Picture.ID = dbo.Product_Picture_Mapping.PictureID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY dbo.Picture.UpdatedDate DESC                               but i have error,   Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The column 'ID' was specified multiple times for 'CTE'. Thank you for your help

Comment: You have to list all columns instead of using the placeholder *. If you have duplicate columns (from diff. Tables) use column aliases.

Comment: Firstly Tahnk you so much for your support, then i want to ask you one  moe thing. can i remove this cloumn(RN) from result pane ? [link](http://i.hizliresim.com/eoyXl7.png)

Comment: Yes, of course. Just omit it from the final select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `top 1 with ties` option.

```
select top 1 with ties *
from ...
order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with TempTb as (Select ID, Name,ShortDesc, Count =ROW_NUMBER()
                over(PARTITION By ID Order By ID)
                From YourTable
                )

Select * from TempTb where Count =1
```